# Caliburn.Micro and TabControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to bind a `ObservableCollection` of viewmodels to a `TabControl`.

In my MainViewModel I have : (`INotifyPropertyChanged` is handled through Fody.PropertyChanged)

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageManagementViewModel> ImageManagement { get; set; }
```

And my MainView :

```
<TabControl
    Margin="5"
    x:Name="ImageManagement" />
```

My `ImageManagementViewModel` implements `IHaveDisplayName`, as [the documentation](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/conventions) seems to indicate is needed.

> If the TabControl’s DisplayMemberPath is not set and the ViewModel implements IHaveDisplayName, then we set it’s ItemTemplate to the DefaultHeaderTemplate, which looks like this: [...]

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the display name
/// </summary>
public string DisplayName
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0}x{1}", this.X, this.Y);
    }
    set
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But my tab's titles are always "TestApplication.ViewModels.ImageManagementViewModel", instead of the DisplayName.
If I implement the DisplayName "by hand" it works, but I'd like it to be automatic, because why doesn't it work ?

```
<TabControl
    Margin="5"
    x:Name="ImageManagement">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemContainerTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        </ItemContainerTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: What returns property DisplayName in getter on your ImageManagementViewModel?

Comment: more than likely the get is returning nothing at runtime so it defaults to the lowest denominator at this point it's the default template.  By not also doing a set with a Notification it will not completely bind the results you want.  DisplayName in the viewmodel needs to be set doesn't mean you have to overload it with your own in implementation just give it something to work with.  DisplayName = string.Format("{0}x{1}", this.X, this.Y), I usually set it in the constructor.

Comment: this also assumes that the name of the tab control is ImageManagement, or you are binding to the ItemsSource manually.

Comment: read reading your problem, does your ImageManagementViewModel need lifecycle aware?  You can inherit from Screen and get all of that + you don't have to reinvent the DisplayName it's already part of Screen class object.

Comment: The `get` should at least return "0x0", since `X` and `Y` are `int`, and an `int` default value is 0. Yes the `x:Name` of the TabControl is ImageManagement. Yes, the viewmodel needs adding stuff in it. I'll try with `Screen` but I'm not sure it will change anything.